# mysql not starting

Tags: server, mysql, lamp, disk-usage

I have a server running on rackspace.com, it been running for about a year (collecting data for a project) and no problems. Now it seems `mysql` froze (could not connect either through `ssh` command line, remote app (sequel pro) or web (pages using the db just froze).

I got a bit eager to fix this quick and rebooted the virtual server, running ubuntu 10.10. It is a small virtual LAMP server (10GB of storage - I'm only using 1.25GB of RAM - has not been a problem). Now after the reboot, I cannot get `mysql` to start again.

```
service mysql status
mysql stop/waiting
```

I believe this just means mysql is not running. How do I get this running again?

```
service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

No. Just typing 'mysql' gives:

```
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

There is a .sock file in this folder, `ls -l` gives:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 2012-12-01 17:20 mysqld.sock
```

I need the data in the database (so i'd like to avoid reinstalling), and I need it back up running again.

Comment: I've learned a new command line trick `du -s -m *` and while rackspace gives no indication I can find, it seems the disk indeed was full: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804021 (the answer to this question on ubuntuforums was disk space). By upgrading to a bigger disk (and doubling my monthly bill), this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP posted his solution as comment, copying it here as answer:

> I've learned a new command line trick `du -s -m *` and while rackspace gives no indication I can find, it seems the disk indeed was full: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804021 (the answer to this question on Ubuntu Forums was disk space). By upgrading to a bigger disk (and doubling my monthly bill), this seems to work fine.

Usually it is a good advice to look at the output of `df` and the sizes of `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/log/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP, digging through the thread he linked to gave me this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

which tries to restart mysql.  In using this command I finally got an error message confirming the problem is the memory being too full:

> /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

Therefore I needed to free up space on the partition.

Comment: Rather silly, but I had /etc/init.d/mysql and /etc/init.d/mysql.server. Not sure why, but first one was wrong. So removed that and linked mysql.server to mysql.