# MySQL not working after server reboot?

Tags: mysql, magento

Because of problem with host company node I migrate from one node to another.

Now the server is working, but there seems to be a problem with mysql. In `directadmin` in `MYSQL Management` i see this message:

```
Error connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The websites are running on Magento and in that error log file there is a message:

```
No such file or directory lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

Is there a way to recover this whitout losing data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to (re)start the MySQL with the following line in a terminal:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Get also a look to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224298/mysql-not-starting) question and the answer.